# Associating high res images with Open Graph objects

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I'm building a testing app for the new FB Timeline and I've noticed that when an application posts activity to a user's timeline, and that user then 'features' the activity, the activity is displayed nice and widescreen but the image used is a scaled up version of the image defined in the og:image meta tag.

My question then: Does anyone know a way to associate a high res image with an open graph object so that it can be displayed nicely as a featured event on a user's timeline?

Comment: After looking through a lot of documentation I found this fleeting reference: "To get larger images, you should specify multiply images with your objects and include the height and width attributes." found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units

I guess this means its possible, but no docs on exactly what meta tags to use